# How to create a custom VC type

Tags: credentials, ssi

I have been using Affinidi's APIs (https://affinidi.com/api) for credential management and right now they provide few set of VC types. I want to create my own VC type and use that in my project. How can I create a new VC type such that the creation and verification works as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinidi currently uses the open-source [@affinidi/vc-data](https://github.com/affinityproject/affinidi-core-sdk/tree/master/sdk/vc-data) repository to manage VC schemas. Feel free to contribute your new VC schema to this repository and we will help you get it merged. You can find detailed information regarding how to create your VC schema [here](https://docs.affinidi.com/schemas/schema-governance/).

Before creating a PR, you may also want to check recent VC schema PRs to the project to not miss anything. Here is a PR for [VCGrantWinnerV1](https://github.com/affinityproject/affinidi-core-sdk/pull/127/files) type, which includes all necessary changes(definitions, exporting, version bump, unit tests).

P.S. We are working on "Affinidi Schema Manager", a new product that will let you create and publish schemas without any coding. So stay tuned for that.